# data of type [(confidence: NSNumber, identifier: NSString)] from Swift coming as value [null, null] on React

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I have data of type [(confidence: NSNumber, identifier: NSString)] I am passing to React from Swift as an NSArray, and although data gets sent to React, it is coming back as [null, null].

Any ideas or suggestions on getting the data as needed? Here's the code for some reference:

```
let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model) { request, _ in
          if let classifications =
            request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation] {
            
            let topClassifications = classifications.prefix(2).map {
              (confidence: $0.confidence as NSNumber, identifier: $0.identifier as NSString)
            }

            self.label = topClassifications as NSArray
            self.sendUpdate()
            print("label is \(self.label)")
        }
      }
```

label is defined at the top as such:

```
@objc var label: NSArray = []
```

sendUpdate is simply a callback on an event to send data back to React:

```
@objc func sendUpdate() {
    if onUpdate != nil {
      onUpdate!(["label": label])
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own answer. I believe the data was coming to React as some object that is not readable on the React side. So to circumvent this, simply make it explicit that the data mapped is to create an Array. To allow React to see this Array, you need to send it as an NSArray.

```
let topClassifications = classifications.prefix(2).map {
              ["confidence": $0.confidence as NSNumber, "identifier": $0.identifier as NSString]
            }
```